# Getting data from an updating website using perl

Tags: perl, lwp

I've been trying to make a perl program that tells me the water level of a river from an updating website (https://www.vizugy.hu/?mapModule=OpGrafikon&AllomasVOA=73F7E310-985C-11D4-BB62-00508BA24287&mapData=Idosor), but my program can't access the website and I'm completely stuck and I'm a beginner.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$url = "https://www.vizugy.hu/?mapModule=OpGrafikon&AllomasVOA=73F7E310-985C-11D4-BB62-00508BA24287&mapData=Idosor";

use LWP::Simple;

$site = get($url) or die "The webpage won't load";

if($site =~ /<strong>(\d+)<\/strong>/ig){
    $waterLevel= $1;
    }else{
    die "Can't find the water level (Vízállás (cm))";
}

if($site =~ /<strong>(\d+.\d+.\d+. \d+.:\d+)<\/strong>/){
    $date = $1;
    }else{
    die "Can't find date (Időpont)";
}


print("The water level in Komarom is $waterLevel cm (Date: $date)\n");
```

I do this for a class and I have to use LWP. The website is in Hungarian and so were the variables, but I tried to translate as much as I could.

Comment: It outputs `The water level in Komarom is 173 cm (Date: 2022.01.26. 07:00)` to me.

Comment: My error message is "The webpage won't load at main.pl line7". Could this be the fault of the IDE I use? My professor said we should use this one: https://www.codingrooms.com/compiler/perl/

Comment: Yes it's due to codingrooms; it gives "500 Can't connect to..." with LWP::UserAgent. And the error isn't specific to the website you're trying to reach..

Comment: BTW, you're using `use strict; use warnings;`, right? :)

Comment: When I see problems with LWP and https, I first check that openssl and LWP::Protocol::https are installed. It's an extra step that doesn't happen automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works as expected from my Linux command line. But I see exactly the same behaviour as you when using this online IDE.

The problem with LWP::Simple is that it's hard to debug what's going wrong. So I've replaced the top part of your code so it uses [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

my $url = "https://www.vizugy.hu/?mapModule=OpGrafikon&AllomasVOA=73F7E310-985C-11D4-BB62-00508BA24287&mapData=Idosor";

use LWP::UserAgent;

print "Make a UA\n";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

print "Request\n";
my $resp = $ua->get($url) or die "The webpage won't load";

print "Response\n";
print $resp->code, ': ', $resp->message, "\n";

my $site = $resp->content;

my ($waterLevel, $date);

if ($site =~ /<strong>(\d+)<\/strong>/ig) {
    $waterLevel= $1;
}else{
    die "Can't find the water level (Vízállás (cm))";
}

if ($site =~ /<strong>(\d+.\d+.\d+. \d+.:\d+)<\/strong>/) {
    $date = $1;
}else{
    die "Can't find date (Időpont)";
}

print("The water level in Komarom is $waterLevel cm (Date: $date)\n");
```

The response I see is:

```
Make a UA
Request
Response
500: Can't connect to www.vizugy.com:433 (Temporary failure in name resolution)
Can't find the water level (Vízállás (cm)) at main.pl line 21
```

So it looks like your online IDE isn't set up correctly to make HTTP requests. You could contact the owners (the email address is on the front page of their site) or you could just report the problem to your lecturer.

Answer (score -1):

Please study following demo code which

- downloads web page
- extracts data from `Javascript` block
- processes obtained data for output
- forms hash `%data`
- outputs data as a table with utilization of [perlform](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $url = 'https://www.vizugy.hu/?mapModule=OpGrafikon&AllomasVOA=73F7E310-985C-11D4-BB62-00508BA24287&mapData=Idosor';
my $req = $ua->get($url);

if ($req->is_success) {
    say 'INFO: Success loading web page';
} else {
    die "Could not head($url): " . $req->status_line;
}

my %data = $req->decoded_content =~ /(\w+) = new Array(.*?);/g;

$data{$_} =~ s/[()']//g for keys %data;

$data{Vizhozam} =~ s/[<sup>|<\/sup>]//g;
$data{Vizhozam} =~ s/(\d+) (\d{3}),(\d{2}) m3/$1$2.$3/g;
$data{Vizho}    =~ s/ \x{b0}//g;
$data{Vizho}    =~ s/(\d+),(\d+)C/$1.$2/g;

for (keys %data) {
    my @array = split(',', $data{$_});
    @array = map { s/^ // && $_ } @array;
    $data{$_} = \@array;
}

#say Dumper(\%data);

my $count = @{$data{Idopont}}-1;
my($date,$level,$flow,$temp);

$^ = "STDOUT_TOP";
$~ = "STDOUT";

for ( 0..$count ) {
    ($date,$level,$flow,$temp) = ($data{Idopont}[$_],$data{Vizallas}[$_],$data{Vizhozam}[$_],$data{Vizho}[$_]);
    write;
}

$~ = "STDOUT_BOTTOM";
write;

format STDOUT_TOP =
+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| Date              | Water level (cm) | Water flow (m3/s) | Water temp (C) |
+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
.

format STDOUT =
| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< |             @>>> |      @>>>>>>>>>>> |          @>>>> |
$date, $level, $flow, $temp
.

format STDOUT_BOTTOM =
+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
.
```

Generated output

```
INFO: Success loading web page
+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| Date              | Water level (cm) | Water flow (m3/s) | Water temp (C) |
+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
| 2022.01.06. 07:00 |              331 |           2620.00 |            5.8 |
| 2022.01.07. 07:00 |              334 |           2650.00 |            5.3 |
| 2022.01.08. 07:00 |              331 |           2620.00 |            4.9 |
| 2022.01.09. 07:00 |              289 |           2240.00 |            4.5 |
| 2022.01.10. 07:00 |              272 |           2100.00 |            4.4 |
| 2022.01.11. 07:00 |              260 |           2010.00 |            4.1 |
| 2022.01.12. 07:00 |              243 |           1880.00 |            3.8 |
| 2022.01.13. 07:00 |              228 |           1770.00 |            3.4 |
| 2022.01.14. 07:00 |              213 |           1660.00 |            3.3 |
| 2022.01.15. 07:00 |              196 |           1550.00 |            3.4 |
| 2022.01.16. 07:00 |              195 |           1540.00 |            3.4 |
| 2022.01.17. 07:00 |              183 |           1470.00 |            3.5 |
| 2022.01.18. 07:00 |              185 |           1480.00 |            3.1 |
| 2022.01.19. 07:00 |              173 |           1410.00 |            2.8 |
| 2022.01.23. 07:00 |              164 |           1360.00 |            2.2 |
| 2022.01.24. 07:00 |              154 |           1300.00 |            2.0 |
| 2022.01.25. 07:00 |              161 |           1340.00 |            2.1 |
| 2022.01.26. 07:00 |              173 |           1410.00 |            2.4 |
+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: This is nice code. But it doesn't get the OP any closer to solving their problem. If you run your code in the online IDE that they have been told to use, then you get exactly the same failure.

Comment: @DaveCross Well, the OP must indicate in his question that he uses particular online IDE to run code. When I read his question the comment which indicated what website he uses was not published yet.

Comment: The comment was there when I wrote my answer (which refers to the online IDE) - and that was seven hours before you wrote yours :-)